# How can I enable brightness control on my iMac 11,3?

Tags: brightness, mac

I have Apple iMac 11,3 (27" LED, purchased in 2011) with a Radeon HD 5750 graphics card. When I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, everything works fine except brightness control. I want to mention that I didn't install any additional driver.

I tried `sudo update-grub` after changing `/etc/default/grub` by `acpi_backlight=vendor` with/without `acpi_osi=Linux`. Nothing changes.

What can I do to fix this issue? Help is appreciated.

Comment: Excuse me, purchased in 2011

Comment: Please edit your question to provide additional information, don't put it into a comment.

Answer (score 0):

1) Download Grub Customizer, first by adding the repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
```

Then update the repositories and install the package grub-customizer,

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

2) In the General settings tab, add `acpi_backlight=vendor` and hit save.

3) Reboot and enjoy brightness control!

NOTE: I've only tested this on the latest release (13.04), can't guarantee this works on any other version.